# What is the definition of DRAIN used as follows “..and I've gone out to have a DRAIN with him.”

Tags: word-usage

What is the definition for "drain" as a NOUN as used by W. Somerset Maugham in

the following: “..and I've gone out to have a DRAIN with him.”

(From the short story "The Fall of Edward Barnard").

I assume it means to have a drink (verb) from, for example, "drain a glass of beer". However, was it ever recognized as a noun or did Maugham throw in a piece of slang he'd heard. Sounds like it may be Irish.

Answer (score 1):

It is OED's sense 3b of the noun - a *drain* meaning a drink.

> b. slang. A drink.
>
> 1836   Dickens Sketches by Boz 1st Ser. I. 284   Two old men who came
>   in ‘just to have a drain’.
>
> 1853   Dickens Bleak House xix. 189   He stood drains round.

I have no idea whether it was originally Irish. It must have gone out of fashion since Somerset Maugham - I have never heard it used.